# @RequestParam omitted but mapping is still done correctly

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I just found that even if I omit the `@RequestParam` annotation on the `organization` parameter, Spring is still able to bind it.

```
@RequestMapping(value="", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String save(String organization){
    logger.info(organization); // it works
}
```

Can anyone points to the documentation that clarifies this behaviour? I have always though that `@RequestParam` was mandatory for binding to work.

Thanks

Comment: This works only when yourvariable is exactly `organization` in the method. But with `@RequestParam` you can match it with any string

Comment: If you have multiple request parameters coming in URI and your method parameters are also in same order then you no need to annotate your arguments, but if order is not same then you have to annotate them with @RequestParam() to mention how the query params will be mapped

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at https://reversecoding.net/spring-mvc-requestparam-binding-request-parameters/ There is an explanation:

> Examples without @RequestParam
>
> Based on the list of
>   HandlerMethodArgumentResolver configured in your application,
>   @RequestParam can also be omitted. If you have a look at the code of
>   method getDefaultArgumentResolvers() of RequestMappingHandlerAdapter
>   there is the following piece of code at the end:
>
> // Catch-all resolvers.add(new
>   RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver(getBeanFactory(), true));
>
> resolvers.add(new ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor(true));
>
> // Catch-all resolvers.add(new
>   RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver(getBeanFactory(), true));
>
> resolvers.add(new ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor(true));
>
> Basically, it’s added to the resolvers a
>   RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver with useDefaultResolution set to
>   true. Looking at the documentation we can see that this means that
>   method argument that is a simple type, as defined in
>   BeanUtils.isSimpleProperty(java.lang.Class), is treated as a
>   request parameter even if it isn’t annotated. The request parameter
>   name is derived from the method parameter name.

Answer (score 1):

Your resolvers do it automatically. When you pass the `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` bean to your resolver, the `BeanUtil` [checks](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html#isSimpleProperty-java.lang.Class-) if the parameter is a primitive value or a simple `String`. If so, it does the binding itself.

Answer (score -1):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest")
@ResponseBody
public String save(String username, String password) {
    return String.format("username=%s  password=%s", username, password);
}
```

Hit the service http://localhost:8080/rest?username=mypwd&password=uname

You will be able to see the result given below.

> **Output:** username=pwd password=uname

Answer (score -2):

here I have some examples for the @RequestParam to provide you,hope they can help you:
`@RequestMapping(value = "/selection/findByField", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody List<selectionsDO> add(@RequestParam(value = "field", required = true) String field,@RequestParam(value = "value", required = true) String value) 
{       return mongoService.findByField(field,value);
    }`

The words "required = true" means that  this field must submit at request.